# how to work select button in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

My select button not work. When I press select button then data shown in Textbox, where I put select button then it works properly.

PHP code

```
$qrydatabind='SELECT ecode, first_name, middle_name, last_name, father_name, mother_name,
          number_of_dependents, dob, gender, identification_mark, marital_status, spouse_name, mobile_number,
          email_id, adhar_id, pan_number, passport_number, tin_number, dl_number FROM USER_MASTER ORDER BY user_id DESC 
          LIMIT 1';
                  $results=  mysql_query($qrydatabind) or die(mysql_error());

                      while( $row =  mysql_fetch_array( $results ) ) {
                        echo
            "
                <div class='table-responsive'>
<table  border='1' style= 'background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b;  ' >
      <thead>
                <tr>
            <th></th>
              <th>Entity Code</th>
              <th>User Id</th> <th>User Name</th> <th>Father Name</th>  <th>Mother Name</th>  <th>No.Of Dependents</th>
              <th>D.O.B</th> <th>GENDER</th> <th>Id Mark</th> <th>MARITAL STATUS</th>  <th>SPOUSE NAME</th>
              <th>Mob. Number</th> <th>E-Id</th> <th>ADHAR-ID</th> <th>PAN-No.</th> <th>PASSPORT-No.</th>
               <th>TIN-NO.</th> <th>DL-No.</th>
            </tr>
                </thead>

                      <tr >        

                        <td><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='select_button'>Select</button> </td> 
                        <td>{$row['ecode']}</td> <td> echo $row[0];</td>
                        <td>{$row['first_name']} {$row['middle_name']} {$row['last_name']}</td>             
                        <td>{$row['father_name']}</td> <td>{$row['mother_name']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['number_of_dependents']}</td> <td>{$row['dob']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['gender']}</td> <td>{$row['identification_mark']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['marital_status']}</td> <td>{$row['spouse_name']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['mobile_number']}</td> <td>{$row['email_id']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['adhar_id']}</td>  <td>{$row['pan_number']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['passport_number']}</td> <td>{$row['tin_number']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['dl_number']}</td>


            </tr> </table>  
              </div>";
        }}

        if(isset($_POST['select_button']))
            {
             $qrydatabind1='SELECT ecode, first_name, middle_name, last_name, father_name, mother_name,
          number_of_dependents, dob, gender, identification_mark, marital_status, spouse_name, mobile_number,
          email_id, adhar_id, pan_number, passport_number, tin_number, dl_number FROM USER_MASTER';
                  $results1=  mysql_query($qrydatabind1) or die(mysql_error());

                      while( $row =  mysql_fetch_array( $results1 ) ) {
                          echo'
                        <tr >                   
                        <td> </td> 

                         <td><input  type="text" value="{$row["first_name"]}" ></td>



            </tr>';

            }
            }
```

Comment: I don't get what are you trying to do. If you want to show some DOM in your page, you need javascript to do it

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `<form action='' method='post'></form>`. So when you say `if(isset($_POST['select_button']))` actually there's nothing to check if isset without the `form` and the method `post`. Try adding it and it should work:

```
**//php code**

    $qrydatabind='SELECT ecode, first_name, middle_name, last_name, father_name, mother_name,
              number_of_dependents, dob, gender, identification_mark, marital_status, spouse_name, mobile_number,
              email_id, adhar_id, pan_number, passport_number, tin_number, dl_number FROM USER_MASTER ORDER BY user_id DESC 
              LIMIT 1';
 $results=  mysql_query($qrydatabind) or die(mysql_error());

 while( $row =  mysql_fetch_array( $results ) ) {
      echo
         "
 <div class='table-responsive'>
     <form action='' method='post'>
          <table  border='1' style= 'background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b;  ' >
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                  <th>Entity Code</th>
                  <th>User Id</th> <th>User Name</th> <th>Father Name</th>  <th>Mother Name</th>  <th>No.Of Dependents</th>
                  <th>D.O.B</th> <th>GENDER</th> <th>Id Mark</th> <th>MARITAL STATUS</th>  <th>SPOUSE NAME</th>
                  <th>Mob. Number</th> <th>E-Id</th> <th>ADHAR-ID</th> <th>PAN-No.</th> <th>PASSPORT-No.</th>
                   <th>TIN-NO.</th> <th>DL-No.</th>
                </tr>
                    </thead>

              <tr>        

                            <td><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='select_button'>Select</button> </td> 
                            <td>{$row['ecode']}</td> <td> echo $row[0];</td>
                            <td>{$row['first_name']} {$row['middle_name']} {$row['last_name']}</td>             
                            <td>{$row['father_name']}</td> <td>{$row['mother_name']}</td>
                            <td>{$row['number_of_dependents']}</td> <td>{$row['dob']}</td>
                            <td>{$row['gender']}</td> <td>{$row['identification_mark']}</td>
                            <td>{$row['marital_status']}</td> <td>{$row['spouse_name']}</td>
                            <td>{$row['mobile_number']}</td> <td>{$row['email_id']}</td>
                            <td>{$row['adhar_id']}</td>  <td>{$row['pan_number']}</td>
                            <td>{$row['passport_number']}</td> <td>{$row['tin_number']}</td>
                            <td>{$row['dl_number']}</td>


                </tr> </table>  
                  </form></div>";
            }}

            if(isset($_POST['select_button']))
                {
                 $qrydatabind1='SELECT ecode, first_name, middle_name, last_name, father_name, mother_name,
              number_of_dependents, dob, gender, identification_mark, marital_status, spouse_name, mobile_number,
              email_id, adhar_id, pan_number, passport_number, tin_number, dl_number FROM USER_MASTER';
                      $results1=  mysql_query($qrydatabind1) or die(mysql_error());

                          while( $row =  mysql_fetch_array( $results1 ) ) {
                              echo'
                            <tr >                   
                            <td> </td> 

                             <td><input  type="text" value="{$row["first_name"]}" ></td>



                </tr>';

                }
                }
```

If you do have a form, and the button is outside of it, I think in this case javascript will help you submit it. Let's say you have like this:

```
<form action='' method='post' id='form_id'>
  <!--your inputs-->
</form>
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='select_button'>Select</button>
```

Then in JS you can use:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form_id");
document.getElementsByClassName("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  form.submit();
});
```